# Выпадающие списки в RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Доброго времени суток, новичок в Ruby, нуждаюсь в помощи. Имеется модель `rating` и поле `:year`, `rating` принадлежит (`belong_to`) модели `chair`. Хочу сделать выпадающий список с выбором года (с радиусом выбора 5 лет), чтобы из базы получить список всех `chair` c рейтингом года, полученного из выпадающего списка.

Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему, пытался записать год в переменную, но так и не разобрался, как передать её в другой метод. Может есть решения намного легче?

**UPD:**

*Не получается* передать переменную (в которой записал год) на другую страничку, чтобы потом по этой переменной вывести записи из базы. Как не странно, но передать объект с параметром получается, а простую переменную - нет. Поэтому решил записать год не в переменную, а в поле модели и передал объект в другой экшн. Тем самым проблема вроде как решилась, но создавать целый объект, передавать его, чтобы потом еще получить бяку в адресной строке, кажется мне просто ужасным.

Comment: Опишите как вы пытаетесь решить проблему, и в каком конкретно месте ошибка или что-то не получается.

Comment: Пришлите код, который не работает. Или читайте [документацию](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease).